# Running Shoutcast from Openshift Permission Denied Error

Tags: action, hook, openshift, shoutcast

I've been following along this [blog](http://blog.piratelufi.com/2013/11/use-openshift-as-a-free-shoutcast-server/) to setup a shoutcast server on openshift using the diy cartridge. After replacing the destip with my server's OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP and editing the action and stop hooks I find that the server isn't starting when I visit the application's url, instead I'm getting:

### 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable

```
Service Temporarily Unavailable

The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.
```

When I checked the log file used in the action hook I'm finding:

### server.log

```
nohup: failed to run command `/var/lib/openshift/xxxx app-id xxxx/app-root/runtime/repo//diy/sc_serv.exe': Permission denied
```

(while using window's shoutcast distribution) and

```
nohup: failed to run command `/var/lib/openshift/xxxx app-id xxxx/app-root/runtime/repo//diy/sc_serv': Permission denied
```

(while using linux's shoutcast distribution)

I've read on several forums that often openshift resets the chmod file permissions and prevents applications from being executed, and that's exactly what I found my openshift application doing (after using filezilla to edit the file permissions). Since sc_serv or sc_serv.exe is the main application (a command line application) to keep the server going I'm wondering how I could get around this odd permissions error.

### start action hook (when I used window's shoutcast distribution)

```
nohup $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/diy/sc_serv.exe $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/diy/sc_serv.conf > $OPENSHIFT_DIY_LOG_DIR/server3.log 2>&1 &
```

### start action hook (when I used linux's shoutcast distribution)

```
nohup $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/diy/sc_serv $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/diy/sc_serv.conf > $OPENSHIFT_DIY_LOG_DIR/server3.log 2>&1 &
```

I'd like to note that the blogger used linux and I'm using windows to edit the openshift repository and I assume that the files extracted from the linux distribution of shoutcast are the same whether from windows or linux, but I clearly can't test that. All I can tell so far is that openshift is blocking the main executable (whether it's linux or windows) which essentially runs the whole service. I've tested the server myself on my own localhost and found it working perfectly so I have no doubt if it were to run (with the right settings listed in this [blog](http://blog.piratelufi.com/2013/11/use-openshift-as-a-free-shoutcast-server/) that it would work.

## Edit: Solved

In order to have the permissions changed and kept that way they need to be edited from git using

```
git update-index --chmod=+x filename
git commit -m 'update file permissions ect...'
git push origin master
```

Comment: If you solved it you might want to submit an answer to your own question. That way others who may have the same issue see what solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After stumbling across more stackoverflow answers (and feel free to link one that explains this I don't remember which one I used) I read that openshift will reset everything (permission wise) on every git push (to retain the safety of the code I assume). So the only way to solve the permissions issue is in fact with git, not through ftp software like filezilla or through ssh. This way changing the chmod will remain permanently.

```
git update-index --chmod=+x filename
git commit -m 'update file permissions ect...'
git push origin master
```

In the end what I have in openshift's diy folder is the linux distribution of shoutcast (which can be extracted with [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/). Modified so that it can be reached through port-forwarding like in this [blog](http://blog.piratelufi.com/2013/11/use-openshift-as-a-free-shoutcast-server/). To reach the server (having set up openshift's tools) all you'll have to do before broadcasting is this in command line:

```
rhc port-forward [app-name]
```

If you're using Sam broadcasting software the good news is that you can easily add a mysql database, and also port-forward into that as well using that same command. Port-forwarding would mean that instead of finding the ip:port for your stream and mysql on openshift you would use localhost or 127.0.0.1 and whatever ports indicated by rhc port-forward. You could also be using your other favorite software to broadcast in which case I'd recommend setting up a batch file like so:

```
cd C:\YourSoftwarePath
start YourSoftware.exe
start rhc port-forward [app-name]
```

If you have hardware doing the streaming like through a [barix box](http://www.barix.com/) there will probably be some way of doing this in some other tricky manner.